# How to put focus on jquery dynamically created textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a new product form with dynamically created textbox for "Available Color".  What I want to do is assign focus on the new textbox.  Here's my code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () { 
colorCounter = 2;
sizeCounter = 2;

$("#addColorButton").click(function () {
    if (colorCounter > 10) {
        alert("Only 10 colors allowed");
        return false;
    }
    //This has been edited to show the solution

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'ColorTextBoxDiv' + colorCounter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Color #' + colorCounter + ' : </label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="AvailableColor' + colorCounter +
        '" id="colorTextbox' + colorCounter + '" value="" >');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#ColorTextBoxesGroup"); 
    $('#colorTextbox' + colorCounter).focus();
    colorCounter++;
   });

});
}); 

</script>

<form name="newProductForm" id="newProductForm" action="index.cfm" method="post">
    <div id='ColorTextBoxesGroup'>
        <div id="ColorTextBoxDiv1">
            <label>Color #1 :</label>
            <input type='text' id='colorTextbox1' name="AvailableColor1" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type='button' value='Add More Colors' id='addColorButton'>
</form>
```

var myTextbox seems to evaluate to "colorTextbox2" after the first click but the focus does not move to the newly created textbox.

If I change the line $('#myTextbox').focus(); to $('#colorTextbox2').focus(); then the focus is moved to the new textbox.  Of course another button click and the focus stays in textbox2.

I would sure appreciate some help on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that: `$('#colorTextbox' + colorCounter).focus();` ???

Comment: That did it!  I guess I tried every combination of colorTextbox and colorCounter but that one.  Stared at it far too long over the last 24 hrs.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff.  I will edit my code above to show your correct answer.

Comment: You could instead post it as answer

Comment: It won't let me answer my own question right now.

Comment: Not enough rep i guess :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target the element, you can concatenate variable into string selector like this:

```
$('#colorTextbox' + colorCounter).focus();
```